# Change HighCharts axis title

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to change the axis title of a HighCharts chart programatically?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
charts.series[0].yAxis.title.text = 'new title';
```

or

```
charts.yAxis[0].title.text = 'new title';
```

(having already set a title when the chart was initialized).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using the following:

```
chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
        text: 'new title'
    });
```

Comment: +1, thanks. Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find it in the official docs.

Comment: This work. but when we export the chart default 'Value' text not change? Any one know the way to fix that?

Comment: that's cool but i need to show the same text on y axis mouseover, then how i can achieve the same. (moverover means like tooltip)

Answer (score 28):

This can be done directly on the `Axis` object using `setTitle` now. For example:

```
chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "Bananas" });
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/x8yzvdLe/). The method signature is:

```
setTitle(Object title, [Boolean redraw])
```

So you could optionally pass a boolean to wait with redrawing. The `title` object takes the same parameters as `xAxis.title` meaning you could pass in styles and several other options as well as the text itself. [The API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setTitle) has the complete information.

Answer (score 15):

I couldn't get either of the above to work, perhaps things have changed since last year... I ended up using:

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
                title:{
                    text: "new title"
                }
            });
```

and it worked nicely...

Comment: I can confirm that only this method worked. Using Highcharts 3.0.9

Answer (score 6):

The above answer has still one problem. Images created from the plot using the export module will show the original title, not the changed one. Add the following line to fix:

```
chart.options.yAxis[0].title.text = 'new title';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo fiddle **to dynamically change y-axis title**. Refer this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/MRxn3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<input type="button" value="Change Y-axis Title to 'My text'" id="my_btn">
```

JS (part of thec code to update the y-axis title on a button click):

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    $('#my_btn').click(function(){
        //alert('hey');
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            title:{
                text:"My text"
            }
        });
        alert('Y-axis title changed to "My text" !');
    });
```

**Refer [Highcharts 'update' function documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update)**  for further details.