# Change HighCharts axis title in 2.1.4

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to change the axis label (like [Change HighCharts axis title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880235/change-highcharts-axis-title/5882403)) but :

```
chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
  text: 'new title'
})
```

This works in HighCharts 2.0.5 but doesn't work anymore in 2.1.4…

Is this still possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Via @hfrntt](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5545&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=15), this works as a temporary fix :

```
 $(chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.element).text('New Label');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've described should be correct. I've experimented with something just as simple: setting the chart title.

```
var chart = //... Simple chart definition

$button = $('#button');
$button.click(function() {
    chart.setTitle("Garbage");
    chart.redraw();
});
```

This simple example should also work, so I suspect you may have found a bug.

Answer (score -2):

// this works as correct implementation and not a fix.

chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({'text':'My text'});

// [highcharts forums](http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=18372)

Comment: // as this is a temporary fix 
( $(chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.element).text('New Label'); )
Setting yAxis title in your highchart could be done with the answer provided.
( with var chart = $("#mychart").highcharts();)

Comment: Edit your answer don't post on comments!